# Add-migration OperationException Error: can't create context

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to use the add-migration command before I update the database, as i've made a few recent changes to some models.

When running the command in Visual Studio Package Manager Console add-migration I get the error:

Unable to create an object of type '####Context'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

using the verbose command informed me of a OperationException:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[namespace.Models.###Context]' while attempting to activate 'BIDC.Website.Models.BIDCWebsiteContext'.

In my startup class I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    services.AddDbContext<BIDCWebsiteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnectionString")));
}
```

The ####Context class constructor looks like:

```
public ####Context(DbContextOptions<####Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Options = options;
        }
        private readonly DbContextOptions<####Context> Options;
```

The class is a child of IdentityDbContext.
The DbContextOptions class has no custom extensions or modifications.

I suspect the issue is related to assigning options to the property Options, as that is the only thing that has changed since the last time I used the command as far as i'm aware. However, I am, as of yet, unsure as to why this would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a nice weekend I came back to this is and discovered the following message above the error:

```
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
```

No application service provider was found.

The issue was I had renamed the CreateHostBuilder method to "CreateBuilder" on the program class.

If you also run into this error or an error with the add-migration command I suggest the following:

1. Run the command with either -verbose or --verbose to get more detailed information.
2. Then carefully read the steps the program takes before reaching the error.

I had wrongly assumed the issue was in the DBContext Class, because that was the object that it wasn't able to construct when the exception occurred, but the actual issue was earlier.